# Angular JS : Concate variable with $scope

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Here is my case , I have an array :

```
var fileParamsArray=['fileThumbanilRetina','fileThumbanilNonRetine','fileThumbanilHdpi' ];
```

and in my view i have :

```
 <input type="file" name="fileThumbanilRetina" file-model="fileThumbanilRetina" />  
 <input type="file" name="fileThumbanilNonRetine" file-model="fileThumbanilNonRetine" />  
 <input type="file" name="fileThumbanilHdpi" file-model="fileThumbanilHdpi" />
```

in my angularJS controller i want to have something like $scope.fileThumbanilRetina but when  try to append array index value to $scope . its not happening 
In my controller Here is my function :

```
   $scope.submitForm = function() {    
      var fileParamsArray = [
              'fileThumbanilRetina',
              'fileThumbanilNonRetine',
              'fileThumbanilHdpi' ];
      for(i=0;i<fileParamsArray.length;i++) {
          var file = $scope.fileParamsArray[i];
          console.log(file);
          //call to service function  
          fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl,fileParamsArray[i]);
      }
   }
```

Please Help

Comment: have u defined $scope.fileParamsArray?

Comment: where is your controller code? post it in your question too.

Comment: If possible, create a fiddle and post the link.

Comment: @jai controller code added .

Comment: @user2717954 , Point is i just want name from that array and than access my scope modal of that name like $scope.fileThumbanilRetina

Comment: then look at @Adrian answer... it should work

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your 'question' right...you want something like

```
for(var i ...)
var file = $scope[fileParamsArray[i]];
...
```